# Get Id of selected item in datalist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-datalist

I am having an input element and a datalist for suggestions. I am feeding the an array of object to datalist for suggestions which looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "9cb98eab-7cd4-47d0-8b30-5512a826a3c0",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "Shahrukh Khan"
    },
    {
        "id": "8133586f-ef81-4200-96e8-aff71858ade4",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "B. Jayashree"
    },
    {
        "id": "f9d186d9-5fb9-484b-93c7-274d0ca75eb7",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "B. Jayashree"
    },
    {
        "id": "b39279f5-e7d4-4013-a785-ce88013d9a76",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "E T Mohammed Basheer"
    },
    {
        "id": "8ea077b0-609e-45c6-a839-7735a87557d7",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "E. T. Mohammed Basheer"
    }
]
```

I want to know the id of selected option of datalist. I know how to get the value (via value of input element). But I don't want the value of selected item, I want the id.

Here is my input and datalist element

```
<div>
    <Input className="add-tag-name-input" id="name-field" list='languages' onChange={this.onNameValueChanged.bind(this)}/>
    <datalist id='languages'>
        {this.state.existing_faces && this.state.existing_faces.map((item,i)=>{
            return <option value= {item.name} />
        })}
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Consider existing_faces as the array I have shown above. How can I get the id of selected option. (There is an id in each object in above array)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the selected item as complete object. Not just the name. Only display the name. In your code you only return the name. But you could return the item or the item.id. The value should be the item. You can still display the name of the item. But passed the object for handling.

Like (Pseudo code):

```
<option value=item>{item.name}</option>
```

Or only the id:

```
<option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
```

Maybe you have to adjust a bit to conform with your code. but the main message is, that you can set a tag value and pass the item as object as option value.

```
<option value={what-ever-you-want}>{what-the-user-will-see}</option>
```

Working native HTML example:

```
<select onchange="console.log(this.value)">
  <option value="id-1">Name 1</option>
  <option value="id-2">Name 2</option>
  <option value="id-3">Name 3</option>
  <option value="id-4">Name 4</option>
</select>
```

Will print the id of the selected item in console of the browser. (Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to show the console)

Comment: How can I do this

Comment: @ApurvG I think he means `<option value= {item} />`

Comment: This won't work. Because value={item} won't show names as the suggestions. It will show item object as suggestion.

Comment: How will I get the Id in say any function then? How to pass the it

Comment: Of course you can display the name. See my code snippet example. Before downrate my answer. -.-

Comment: I want to get the id of selected item in some function and also show the input value as item.name when something is slected. How can i do it

Comment: Maybe you have to adjust a bit to conform with your code. but the main message is, that you can set a tag value and pass the item as object as option value.

Comment: How about this <option value= {item.name} onClick={this.selectedOption.bind(this, item)}/>  Doesn't work though

Comment: I get your point. But How to access the id of selected option anywhere in my code?

Comment: You could also just set the item.id as value. See my second snippet. What you want. But you always display the name. <option value={what-ever-you-want}>{what-the-user-will-see}</option>

Answer (score -1):

You could put the id from the array as a value in the JSX.

`<option value= {item.name} data-id={item.id} />`

Comment: and then? How to get it in any function

Comment: Good question. You can put the id in the value as suggested by Dominik but this isn't preferable as it shows to the user. I am otherwise unable to get it out of the `event.target` using react.