# ReactJS: Getting ID from datalist

Tags: reactjs, datalist

I'm dealing with the problem - how to get employee ID of selected item from dynamic datalist in ReactJS.

```
const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

const getData = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get(URL);
   setEmployees(response.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);

const handleChange = (event) => {
 console.log(event.target.value);
};



<input id="employeeName"
   list="listOfEmployees"
   onChange={handleChange}
></input>

<datalist id="listOfEmployees">
   {employees && employees.length > 0 ? (
   employees.map((result) => {
    return (
    <option key={result.id} value={result.name}> {result.name}</option>
          );
          })
       ) : (
        <div>Data loading in progress...</div>
         )}
 </datalist>
```

Here I created example application with this scenario:
https://codesandbox.io/s/get-id-from-datalist-pcghn

Few years ago user Dominik answered on similar question, but I can't realize how to return whole object (in this case it's *employee*) to handleChange function in order to get ID.
[Get Id of selected item in datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896914/get-id-of-selected-item-in-datalist)

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to create a new state for the employee you selected, then you just have to find in your handleChange like so :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({});

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    setEmployees(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setEmployee(employees.find(e => e.name === event.target.value))
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Choose Employee From List</h1>

      <table id="tblEmployees">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label htmlFor="employeeName"> Employee Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                id="employeeName"
                list="listOfEmployees"
                onChange={handleChange}
              ></input>
              <datalist id="listOfEmployees">
                {employees && employees.length > 0 ? (
                  employees.map((employee) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={employee.id} value={employee.name}>
                        {employee.name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <div>Data loading in progress...</div>
                )}
              </datalist>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <label htmlFor="employeeId"> Employee ID</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input id="employeeId" value={employee ? employee.id : ''}/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your input just add the value of the employee id you just selected.

Comment: I would use ‘find’ over filter here, since it returns one result rather than an array

Comment: Also you should not pass `null` to input value . it will throw warning and you should not use value prop without onChange . It will throw warning for this as well .

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to autopopulate the value of the employee id based on the selected employee , you need to have one state to hold the value of selected employee.

```
const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee] = useState("");
```

Now pass this state to the input to make it as a controlled component.

```
 <input
     id="employeeName"
     list="listOfEmployees"
     onChange={handleChange}
     value={selectedEmployee}
  />
```

set the employee to the state when we select or change something in the input .

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedEmployee(event.target.value);
  };
```

Now we have the selectedEmployee's name in the state when you select the employee in the dropdown.

Once we have the employee name we can find the id .

```
const selectedEmployeeId =
    selectedEmployee.trim().length > 0
      ? employees.find((employee) => employee.name === selectedEmployee)?.id ||
        ""
      : "";
```

Now pass this selectedEmployee Id to the default value prop of your second input.

```
<td>
    <input id="employeeId" defaultValue={selectedEmployeeId}></input>
</td>
```

**Working Sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-id-from-datalist-forked-gzrom?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the list of employees stored in state, you could do `employees.find(emp => emp.name === event.target.value)` within your handleChange.

If you just need the id, why not set the `label` of option to be `employee.name` and the value to be `employee.id`? That way you wouldn’t have to perform an operation of N runtime each time you select