# how can I get attributes of selected option of datalist on input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html

```
Area: <input onchange="loadInfo()" id="area_input" list="areas" placeholder="choose option: ">
<datalist id="areas" >
        <option abrv="TV"> TV </option>
        <option abrv="NOT"> NOTEBOOK </option>
        <option abrv="ARC"> AIR CONDITIONING </option>
        <option abrv="PIN"> PINS </option>
</datalist>
```

I learned that when the user selects an option, I can get its value via Javascript doing

```
document.getElementById('area_input').value
```

My objective is to get the *'abrv'* attribute, however I noticed it does not get carried to *input* tag.

How can I get attributes from the selected option via JS?

P.S. (my intention is to use it to append to a DJANGO url 'database/area/[abrv]' and even if on this specific case I can do some work-around striping the *value* string, on the future I will need to get codes from strings)

I tried this solution:
[image] FROM [Get Id of selected item in datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896914/get-id-of-selected-item-in-datalist)

it ended up showing things in a weird way[image: tried_solution result]
the resulting code was like this

```
`<datalist id="areas">
 
        <option value="IMC">IMC</option>
    
        <option value="INJ">INJEÇÃO PLÁSTICA</option>
    
        <option value="NOT">NOTEBOOK</option>
    
        <option value="TRA">TRANSFORMADOR</option>
    
        <option value="TV">TV</option>
    
</datalist>`
```

the solution told me user would see only what was inside the tag, but on cases where the attribute *value* was different than the actual *value* inside the tag it showed the user both info, I wanted to show only the full text to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store extra information in data-* attributes. Then search options list for match by input's value:

HTML

```
<input onchange="loadInfo()" id="iareas" list="areas" placeholder="choose option: ">
    <datalist id="areas" >
        <option data-value="TV">TV</option>
        <option data-value="NOT">NOTEBOOK</option>
        <option data-value="ARC">AIR CONDITIONING</option>
        <option data-value="PIN">PINS</option>
    </datalist>
```

SCRIPT

```
function loadInfo() {
        const data = document.getElementById("areas");
        const opts  = data.options;

        const v = document.getElementById("iareas").value;
        for(let i=0; i<opts.length; i++) {
            const o = opts[i];
            if(o.text === v) {
                console.log(o.getAttribute("data-value")); //do anything with value
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```